# Problem with Mozilla Firefox and function execution

Tags: jquery, function, firefox, execution

Hi all I have a problem with this code. When I try the code under IExplorer 9, Chrome 12.0.742.30 dev and Opera 11.10 - the code works properly but under Firefox 3 and 4 generation the code works slowly. I mean when I'm at third picture and picture size is 400x400px and I press "previous"/"next" the function updateLightBox() must resize the container with size of second picture but it doesn't. Second picture size is 200x200px but the next time when I press "previous"/"next" the container will get this size, but first image is with different size and the image isn't on the center of display and buttons are not on their places.

```
$('div#next').unbind().bind('click', function() {
    if(currentImage == arrayLength-1) {
        var Image = 0;
    }
    else {
        var Image = currentImage+1;
    }
    $('img#image').attr('src', imageArray[Image]);
    updateLightBox();
    cfg.activeImage = Image;
    currentImage = Image;
});
$('div#prev').unbind().bind('click', function() {
    if(currentImage == 0) {
        var Image = arrayLength-1;
    }
    else {
        var Image = currentImage-1;
    }
    $('img#image').attr('src', imageArray[Image]);
    updateLightBox();
    cfg.activeImage = Image;
    currentImage = Image;
});
```

The function updateLightBox() is:

```
function updateLightBox() {
    var imgWidth = $('img#image').width();
    var imgHeight = $('img#image').height();
    var top = (height - imgHeight) / 2;
    var left = (width - imgWidth) / 2;

    $('div#imgAlt').remove();
    $('span#imgNum').remove();
    $('div#alt').append('<div id="imgAlt">'+altArray[cfg.activeImage]+'</div>');
    $('div#alt').append('<span id="imgNum">'+(cfg.activeImage+1)+' / '+arrayLength+'</span>');
    $('img#image').attr('alt', altArray[cfg.activeImage]);

    $('div#lightbox').animate({
        'top': top,
        'left': left,
        'width': imgWidth+'px',
        'max-width': imgWidth+'px',
        'min-width': cfg.minContainerWidth+'px',
        'height': imgHeight+'px',
        'max-height': imgHeight+'px',
        'min-height': cfg.minContainerHeight+'px'
    }, cfg.containerResizeSpeed);

    $('div#image').animate({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'margin': 0,
        'padding': 0,
        'zIndex': 902,
    }, cfg.containerResizeSpeed);

    $('div#alt').animate({ 
        'width': imgWidth-20+'px',
    }, cfg.containerResizeSpeed);

    $('div#prev').animate({
        'top': (imgHeight / 2) - 16+'px',
    }, cfg.containerResizeSpeed);

    $('div#next').animate({
        'top': (imgHeight / 2) - 16+'px',
    }, cfg.containerResizeSpeed);

    $('div#imgAlt').css({
        'font-family': 'Times New Roman, Georgia, Serif',
        'font-size': '14px',
        'font-weight': 'bold',
        'color': cfg.altTextcolor,
    });

    $('span#imgNum').css({
        'font-family': 'Times New Roman, Georgia, Serif',
        'font-size': '11px',
        'font-weight': 'bold',
    });
}
```

If anyone knows how to fix it and tell me I'll be very happy and grateful :)

With regards,
George :]

Answer (score 0):

Your setting currentImage after you call the update function

```
updateLightBox();
cfg.activeImage = Image;
currentImage = Image;
```

Should be

```
cfg.activeImage = Image;
currentImage = Image;
updateLightBox();
```

Comment: It's the same result. Before I post this the script were the same... Like the second in your post...

Comment: I fix the script and now works properly under all browsers :]

Comment: @T0m3kk Glad to hear it What was the issue? (post as answer and accept it)

Comment: Just I encircled the issue :) I can't post the fix because the fix is 81 lines - more than 2000 symbols :) Just I remove this function and added it in binds of divs. And i make a little change in the function :) If U still interested I'll show u the code :)

Comment: @ T0m3kk no small fix then :)